# What is the best way to split "[{a},{b},{c}]" into a string array "a,b,c"

Tags: c#

What is the ***best*** way to split "[{a},{b},{c}]" into a `string` array `t` such as:

```
t[0] == "a"
t[1] == "b"
t[2] == "c"
```

Consider the input string as verbatim, square and curly brackets are actually there.

**UPDATE:**
Here is a more concrete sample of what I need to split

```
[{ pk:"4",id:"4",cb_program_id:"2.0000",DataSource:"1",Status:"0",CutoffDate:"15/10/2012 14:05:04" }, 
{ pk:"3",id:"3",cb_program_id:"2.0000",DataSource:"1",Status:"0",CutoffDate:"15/10/2012 14:05:02" }, ... ]
```

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be "covered" against the chance of having occurences of [ or { or ] or } or commas in the inner strings (i.e. a,b,c)

Comment: please edit your question to show of an example of such a case - desired input/output.

Comment: if you are going to have your delimiter characters in the substrings you need a defined way of escaping them.

Comment: I was more thinking of a split by regex maybe

Answer (score 6):

Use [`String.Split`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx&ei=eQjsUJDrIumb0QWJuYCYAQ&usg=AFQjCNEjWM5hb_GjmluDIrNyKTWBNHozeA&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k) to get rid of all the unwanted characters.

```
"[{a},{b},{c}]".Split(new char[] {'[', ']', '{', '}', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Edit: Following OP's edit, @Daniel's answer is more suitable for maintaining integrity of the substrings.

Comment: That would be `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`?

Comment: @Jon sorry, yeah, I keep expecting SO to autocomplete my code :)

Comment: How about `.Split("[]{},".ToCharArray(), ...` instead of `.Split(new char[] {'[', ']', '{', '}', ','}, ...`?

Answer (score 4):

```
var t = s.Trim('[', ']').Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('{', '}')).ToArray();
```

This will first remove the outer brackets, split by the comma and remove the curly braces at the beginning and the end of the result.

To cover embedded special characters like comma or curly braces, you need to escape them, because otherwise there will exist ambiguous strings that could be splitted in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working example:

```
string str = "[{a},{b},{c}]";
string[] t = str.Split(new char[] { '[', ']', '{', '}', ',' },
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .ToArray();
```

Output:

```
t[0] == "a"
t[1] == "b"
t[2] == "c"
```